# The du'a of Uthman ibn Hunaif RA

Tags: hadith-interpretation

I need some clarification on the meaning of the du'a recommended by Uthman ibn Hunaif RA to a blind man during the caliphate of Uthman ibn Affan RA :

> Imam Tabrani has narrated an incident that a person repeatedly visited Uthman bin Affan (ra) concerning something he needed but Uthman paid no attention to him. the man went to Uthman bin Hunaif (ra) and complained to him about the matter- so Uthman bin Hunaif said : “Go to the place of Wudu, then come to the Masjid, perform two Rak’ats and then say : “O Allah!, I ask you and turn to you through our Prophet Muhammad, the Prophet of Mercy. **O Muhammad! I turn through you to my lord, that He fulfil my need**” and mention your need. Then come so that I can go with you [to the caliph Uthman] So the man left and did as he had been told, then went to the door of Uthman ibn Affan (Allah be pleased with him), and the doorman came, took him by the hand, brought him to Uthman ibn Affan, and seated him next to him on a cushion. ‘Uthman asked, “What do you need?” and the man mentioned what he wanted, and Uthman accomplished it for him …(till the end of hadith)
>
> (MAJMA AZ-ZAWAID VOLUME NO.2 HADITH 3668)

I'm still confused over the wording of this du'a. What significance was there to recite it in the **second person**? It implies the direct intercession of the Prophet SAW. The Prophet SAW was not expected to hear it nor was it expected that he SAW would actually supplicate to Allah SWT at that very moment since he SAW is buried and can only hear us if we visit his SAW blessed grave. How could this du'a be effective if a supplication by the Prophet SAW was **not actually performed let alone expected**? Could there be a deeper meaning to it?

Comment: As you quoted the source of this statement being Mahma' az-Zawaid of al-Haythami didn't the author leave a comment of the authenticity of this narration?

Comment: The hadith was declared as Sahih by at-Tabarni according to al-Haythami in [Majam' az-Zawaaid](https://islamweb.net/ar/library/index.php?page=bookcontents&ID=3672&bk_no=87&flag=1) and it is quoted in [Jami' at-Tirmidhi](https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi:3578) and [Sunan ibn Majah](https://sunnah.com/ibnmajah/5/583) too.

Comment: Akhi I'm not actually asking whether it's authentic or not. I do believe it's authentic. Why I need is it's meaning

Comment: I know, but it is better to clarify sources and authenticity first before discussing a hadith that might be fabricated.

Comment: Akhi I think I've figured it out. Is it **possible** that the Prophet SAW made Allah SWT promise that He SWT would Aid/Ease/Forgive those who supplicate via this du'a? By definition the Prophet SAW had interceded on behalf of the coming righteous generations who would use this supplication and he SAW begged Allah SWT to Answer their prayers on his SAW behalf. This is my interpretation. Allah SWT knows best. What do you think?

Comment: Akhi r u not gonna ban this "Islam is false" guy?